# overwriting package migration in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to overwrite the migration of a package inside of `vendor/pkgnamespace/pkgname/src/migrations/2222_create_table.php`

So the ideal case if I could define it in  `app/migrations/pkgnamespace/pkgname/2222_create_table.php` and it would execute when I do php artisan migrate pkg:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Nope, packages migration is not using any cascading filesystem.

Comment: what about if the package has routes and filters I wanted to modify, where would I do that?